# Domain not working after transfer from GoDaddy to AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have transferred my domain **techhunters.net** from GoDaddy to AWS Route53.
I have added hosted zone and created record set. Settings are given below.
[image]

Its been more than 48 hours still browser shows **techhunters.net’s server IP address could not be found**.

Comment: can you share godaddy setting which you change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using Godaddy nameservers:

`dig -t ns techhunters.net`

Output:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
techhunters.net.    3600    IN  NS  ns73.domaincontrol.com.
techhunters.net.    3600    IN  NS  ns74.domaincontrol.com.
```

Quite likely, Godaddy will stop serving your domain name from the moment you transfer it away.

Basically, you defined your zone at AWS but you have yet to make it active.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-procedure